# ARIMA PREDICT doesnt forecast (But works for Hindcasting)

Tags: python, statsmodels, forecasting, predict, arima

When using `ARIMA` I can hind-cast past data as shown below but the moment I try to forecast future values, it doesn't work.

And yes I have added new rows to my table using `concat`:

```
df['forecast'] = results.predict(start = 50, end = 251)
df[['close', 'forecast']].plot(figsize = (12,8))
```

[image: enter image description here]]

But the moment I change `end = 251` to `end= 252`, it doesn't produce any forecast values and all my `hind-cast` values disappear?

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use forecast instead of predict:

```
df['forecast'] = results.forecast(steps=7)
```

There's a good tutorial on this here:  https://machinelearningmastery.com/make-sample-forecasts-arima-python/